# Best way to restructure JSON content based on parent-child relationships in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.10

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{
  "id": "28146891_absf",
  "content": "random sentence A",
  "edges": []
},
{
  "id": "48XX_cd5Q",
  "content": "random sentence 2",
  "edges": [
    {
      "target": "VJuAqCSn8",
      "type": "child"
    },
    {
      "target": "rQPhBJ16x",
      "type": "parent"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "rQPhBJ16x",
  "content": "random sentence 1",
  "edges": [
    {
      "target": "48XX_cd5Q",
      "type": "child"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "VJuAqCSn8",
  "content": "random sentence 3",
  "edges": [
    {
      "target": "48XX_cd5Q",
      "type": "parent"
    }
  ]
}
.....................]
```

and I want to convert it into something like this:

```
[{
  "id": "28146891_absf",
  "content": "random sentence A"
},
{
  "id": "rQPhBJ16x",
  "content": "random sentence 1",
  "children": [{
      "id": "48XX_cd5Q",
      "content": "random sentence 2",
      "children":[{
          "id": "VJuAqCSn8",
          "content": "random sentence 3",
          "children": []
      }]
  ]
 }, ........
]
```

Parents can have multiple different children that can again have multiple different children recursively. It is not necessarily the case that children and parents are located next to each other or in order in the data as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: well, you have to parse the data and assemble the data structure yourself. Having to understand the "type" value is too specific to the data youhva,e and you will have to code it up

Comment: @jsbueno, but is there a way I could use a data class or something like that to define the structure and then iterate through the JSON content? If so, how does one proceed that way, and are there specific examples I can look at for help?  I'm a beginner coder.

Comment: There are ways to build using O.O. so thatthe code gets quite confortable to work. But specially if you are a begginer, you should not worry about that, and exercise the basic blocks, so that you feel confortable: a function, that will receive a node and the whole list, create a new node with the `children` key and feed it based on "if/else" blocks . It is very important to be comfortable with that.